python webbrowser returns 'True' when when opening and closing url
Webbrowser returns 'True' when the script opens and closes.
I have a script with many buttons, here I have reduced the error to one button.
I have tried the 'simple webbrowser' as well with same result. I have searched the web for similar errors, but did not find anyone else with the same problem. Can you help?
I have used both Kivy 2.2.1 and 2.2.0. Python 3.8.10 and Pydroid3.
Here is the script:
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    import webbrowser
    #import simple_webbrowser as swb
    #from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

    kv_text = '''

    <MyScreenManager>:
        HomeScreen:

    <HomeScreen>:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: ['11dp','8dp']
            spacing: '10dp'        
           
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1,.1
                orientation: "horizontal"
                    
                Button:          
                    id:results_where
                    text:'Where \\nto stay'
                    background_color:[1,0,0,1]
                    on_press:app.root.btn()                                                                                                                     
    '''

    class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
        pass
            
    class MyButtons(BoxLayout):
        #def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            #super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def mybutton_where(self):       
            wb=webbrowser.open('https://www.montagu.org.za/accommodation/') 
            return wb
            
    class HomeScreen(Screen):
        #def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            #super(HomeScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)        

        def btn(self):
            alt=MyButtons.mybutton_where(self)
            self.ids['results_where'].text= str(alt)

    class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return HomeScreen()
            
    def main():
        Builder.load_string(kv_text)
        app = MyApp()
        app.run()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()


That is expected. webbrowser.open() returns True if it could open the page.
(I created an upstream PR to document this better: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/123495)

Thanks for your response. I do realize that the response is True, but I don't want it printed on de screen. I have gone through all your documentation but I still don't really know what to do? Do I have to write code to not print 'True' ?

I have ticked because I know the answer is correct (I've copied lines 88 -92 and I'll try to take it from there. Thanks anyway. Rgds

If you don't want True on the screen, don't do self.ids['results_where'].text= str(alt) ...
